# In Zf2, how to add a error css class on validation failed

Tags: php, css, validation, zend-framework2

I want to add red border around Input Text Box when ZF2 Validation failed. I am thinking if ZF2 provide way to add/set css class in case of validation failure. 
It is better if it is possible using only Zend Validation/Form API.  I am not considering client side (javascript/jQuery) solutions.

UPDATE :

I am using Form Row element like that

```
<div class="row">
    <div><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('first_name')); ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('first_name')); ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('first_name'), array('class' => "field-validation-error")); ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How come php(ZF2) style the forms? AFAIK, you should go with client side languages like javascript. create the package at backend(ZF2) and send it to javascript to apply your required stylings. Note: the validation is not operating by client side language which I explained above.

Comment: @Mr_Green he is talking about customizing how ZF2 view helpers render the HTML. he is not talking about styling itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FormRow view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formrow), which will render non-valid elements with CSS class ("input-error" by default).

Usage is very simple, in your template:

```
echo $this->formRow($element);
```

or if you want custom class:

```
echo $this->formRow()->setInputErrorClass('my-error-class')->render($element);
```

Comment: Could be good, but I am not using formRow but using separate formElement . See my updated question.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj : Then I suggest using FormRow view helper with partial, which is custom template with all related data to form element - you can then render it on your own and reuse it whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add specific 'error' classes to the input will need to modify the related `Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form*` classes as these are what introspect the `Zend\Form\ElementInterface` objects and render the required HTML.

For example:

```
// \MyModule\Form\View\Helper\MyCustomFormElement.php
class MyCustomFormElement extends \Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement
{

    public function render(Element $element)
    {
        $errors = $element->getMessages();

        if (! empty($errors)) {

            $classes = $element->getAttribute('class');

            if (null === $classes) $classes = array();
            if (! is_array($classes)) $classes = explode(' ', $classes);

            $classes = array_unique(array_merge($classes, array('my-error-class')));

            $element->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $classes));
        }

        return parent::render($element);
    }

}
```

Then just replace the default form element helper by registering a invokable with the same name.

```
// Module.php
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'form_element' => 'MyModule\Form\View\Helper\MyCustomFormElement',
        ),
    );
}
```