# ZF2 Render Custom Class on Form Validation Error

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form2

How can I wrap a fieldset tag around my form rows, and how can I add a has-danger class to the fieldset when an element fail to validate?

I think I need to create a viewhelper, check if a specific formelement has a validation message and wrap the row with a fieldset, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach or how to do it.

The output I want on validation error:

```
<fieldset class="has-danger"><label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control 
input-error" value="f"><ul><li>Needs to be    5-20 characters long</li>
</ul></fieldset>
```

register.phtml:

```
<?php
$form = $this->registerForm;
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

echo $this->formHidden($form->get('secret'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('username'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('password'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('confirm-email'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag($form);
```

Comment: Hello @user1989781 could you paste your *.phtml code for more precisions ?

Comment: possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183321/in-zf2-how-to-add-a-error-css-class-on-validation-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should use the `formLabel()`, `formElement()` and `formElementErrors()` view helpers instead of `formRow()`.

To my ZF2 knowledge, the `formRow()` view helper doesn't let you have control on the HTML output easily. It displays the complete input HTML (label + input + errors) in one line of code.

To simply achieve your goal, your phtml structure for one input has to be as follow :

```
// NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE.phtml
<?php
    $userNameInput       = $form->get('username');
    $userNameInputErrors = $this->formElementErrors($userNameInput);
?>
<fieldset class="<?= $userNameInputErrors ? 'has-danger' : '' ?>" >
    <?= $this->formLabel($userNameInput) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($userNameInput) ?>
    <?= $userNameInputErrors ?>
</fieldset>
```

This is a hard work to do this for each fields in form, so I suggest you to put this logic in a view helper.

```
// MyFormRow.php 
<?php
    namespace Your\Namespace;

    use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

    class MyFormRow extends AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $formLabelViewHelper;
        protected $formElementViewHelper;
        protected $formElementErrorsViewHelper;

        public function __construct($formLabelViewHelper, $formElementViewHelper, $formElementErrorsViewHelper)
        {
            $this->formLabelViewHelper         = $formLabelViewHelper;
            $this->formElementViewHelper       = $formElementViewHelper;
            $this->formElementErrorsViewHelper = $formElementErrorsViewHelper;
        }

        public function __invoke($formElement)
        {
             $html = '';

             $errors = $this->formElementErrorsViewHelper->__invoke($formElement);     

             $html .= '<fieldset class=" . ($errors ? 'has-danger' : '') . ">';    
                 $html .= $this->formLabelViewHelper->__invoke($formElement); 
                 $html .= $this->formElementViewHelper->__invoke($formElement);  
                 $html .= $errors;   
             $html .= '</fieldset>';

             return $html;
        }
    }
?>
```

Declare it in your `Module.php`.

```
// In your Module.php
<?php

    ...

    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories'  => [
                'myFormRow' => function (HelperPluginManager $helperPluginManager) {
                    $formLabelViewHelper        = $helperPluginManager->get('formLabel');
                    $formElementViewHelper      = $helperPluginManager->get('formElement');
                    $formElementErrorsViewHelper = $helperPluginManager->get('formElementErrors');

                    return new MyFormRow($formLabelViewHelper, $formElementViewHelper, $formElementErrorsViewHelper);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
?>
```

And now in your phtml file, simply :

```
// NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE.phtml

...

<?= echo $this->myFormRow($form->get('username')) ?>

...
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
For some reason I had to call the invoke method in my view helper, like:
$html .= $this->formLabelViewHelper->__invoke($formElement);

btw you wrote the wrong method name when instantiating $errors.